# Error:(191, 78) error: cannot find symbol variable ARGB_8888 in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

In **Edit_Staff** activity, there is an `ImageView`. The `ImageView` will display the image which was fetched from `MySQL`.

```
private void showStaff(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            String image=c.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE);
            byte[] data= Base64.decode(image,0);
            Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
            image1.setImageBitmap(b);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Below the `imageView`, it has a change picture `button`, for user to change picture.

```
 public void activeGallery()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                    null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    Bitmap a = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    photo = scaleBitmap(a, 200, 150);
                    image1.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }

  public Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,int newWidth,int newHeight) {
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);

        float ratioX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
        float ratioY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
        float middleX = newWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = newHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, middleX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;
    }
```

In order to fetch the image from MySQL , I use this library

```
import com.example.project.myapplication.Handler.Config;
```

However, `Config.ARGB_8888` inside scaleBitmap cannot be solved. I changed to
 `import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;`, but `Config.TAG_IMAGE` inside showStaff cannot be resolved.

How can I solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the error because your `Config` class doesn't have the field `ARGB_8888`.

You could change your class name to something other than `Config` to use them both with the imports, or you could use the full namespace of the [`android.graphics.Bitmap.Config`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html).

Something like:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
// The rest of your code
// ...
// And make a call somewhat like this:
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

But I think it's just quicker to rename your `Config` class to something like `Configs` to avoid namespace conflicts.

Read more about classes and namespace [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_11.htm), also, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764742/java-namespace-two-classes-with-the-same-name-in-different-packages).

Comment: `import android.graphics.Bitmap.config;` cannot resolved config

Comment: It's a capital C, sorry, my bad. It's Config, not config.

Comment: Do I need to rename my Config class if I use android.graphics.Bitmap.Config. ?

Comment: It's one option. Rename to something like `Configs`, to avoid the namespace conflicts.

Comment: I've edited the answer, take a look. Both approaches will work, chose the one you feel like it's best for you.

Comment: I rename the class Config to Configs, and `import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;` and
`import com.example.project.myapplication.Handler.Configs;`, but it said `import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;` unused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99998/discussion-between-mauker-and-tony).

Comment: `Error:(192, 20) error: cannot find symbol method setScale(float,float,float,float)` and `Error:(195, 26) error: incompatible types: android.opengl.Matrix cannot be converted to android.graphics.Matrix`